# How to configure hive server to run on remote mode?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-plugins

i added hive package to my hadoop cluster. if i go into hive cli, i can run hive in remote mode. but queries going through hive server runs in local mode which is really slow... the only changes i did to hive is to set up derby network server, following this link: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HiveDerbyServerMode
i also have exported HADOOP_CONF_DIR, HADOOP_HOME, HIVE_CONF_DIR, HIVE_HOME in my environment...

anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first follow the wiki page here to get things set up: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer

it turns out there's an environment issue. i was running hive server using another user:
   sudo -u op
but the system resets all environment variables for that user under sudo command. the fix i put in is to put environment variable names in env_keep in /etc/sudoers. after that hive server is running in remote mode now.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. how did you set up environment variable in the sudoers?? can you please share the steps. thanks a lot.